# JSF + backing bean: How to detect when the application first load

Tags: java, jsf

How do I do something like this
`Inside JSF file, list.xhtml`

```
 <p:dataTable value="#{document.drawings}" var="item">
     //document is the backing bean that has method getDrawings() that return list of item
 </p:dataTable>
```

`Inside my backing bean, document.java`

```
 List<Drawing> drawings;
 ...
 public void List<SelectItem> getDrawings(){
      if(application first load){
           return sessionBean.getAllDrawings();
      }else{
           return drawings;
      }
 }
```

So the logic is that if the application first load, then load every thing from the datasource, by accessing method `getAllDrawings()` inside `session bean`, otherwise return `drawings` which is the list of Drawing that has been manipulate by some ajax method.

Comment: What do you mean by application first load? Do you mean the first time this page is displayed to this user?Or only for first ever visit to this page,no matter who the user is?

Comment: First time when the page is visited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() { 
      drawings = loadDrawings();
}
```

But you can also have the so-called "lazy-loading". I.e.:

```
public void List<SelectItem> getDrawings(){
      if(drawings == null) {
           drawings = sessionBean.getAllDrawings();
      }
      return drawings;
}
```

Comment: I try your method, both of them work great. TY. However, I got one more question. So when the page first loads, it loads let say 6 drawings. Then i filters it down to 4 drawings. I click on 1 of the drawing to take me to another page. However, when I click the back button, it go back to the first page, but now it load 6 drawings. Is there a way that I can go back to the original page where I filter down to 4 drawings

Comment: That's quite a different question - ask a new one, providing the relevant code

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as an **application** scoped bean and put the desired application-startup-initialization logic in its constructor. You can if necessary inject it as `<managed-property>` (or if you're already on JSF 2.0, as `@ManagedProperty`) in any other request/session scoped bean.

An application scoped bean is created only once and shared among all sessions/requests during webapplication's lifetime.

Comment: Can u explain a bit about why do I need `@ManagedProperty`?

Comment: It's useful if you want to access *other* bean from inside a bean. I can imagine that you don't want to use an application scoped bean to handle form submits and so on, but rather a request scoped bean.